# How to track blog changes without a feed?

Tags: rss, blogging, atom-feed, subscription

Some of the blogs like the one from [Datameer](http://datameer.com/blog/) don't have any feeds, but still I would like to get the changes to the blog in Google Reader.

Google Reader used to support this [feature](http://googlereader.blogspot.com/2010/01/follow-changes-to-any-website.html), but it no more works.

Any alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The google thread [manually create a feed](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/reader/thread?tid=0a64fb7a040dfa9d&hl=en) treats exactly your problem.

The advice there is to use [Page2RSS](http://page2rss.com/), a website that claims :

> Page2RSS is a service that helps you monitor web sites that do not
>   publish feeds. It will check any web page for updates and deliver them
>   to your favorite RSS reader.

I tried it by entering your datameer.com blog url into their "Page URL" field, hit the "to RSS" button, then under "Subscribe to Feed:" I clicked on "Google Reader". It then passed me to a google page where the button "Add to Google Reader" seems to have really added a feed to Google Reader.

Answer (score 3):

There are various sites that can create RSS feeds from webpages. page2rss.com was already mentioned. See also [feedity.com/](http://feedity.com/) and [feed43.com/](http://feed43.com/).

(Also see [Yahoo pipes tool](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=NlNQKdO62xGAq1ZgZoQMOQ) which uses feedity. Yahoo pipes is useful for combining feeds and other stuff.)